# Overwrite a variable within FOR loop

Tags: python

In my Python code I am trying to iterate a Gaussian function.

I am defining a variable `x0 = 2`, then I do maths on it with a For loop and then I am trying to overwrite the value of `x0` with the value of `x_test`. I want to loop it over many times in order to get the shape of the Gaussian function (so I guess like Monte Carlo method).

What I cannot do is figure out how to overwrite the value of `x0` with the value of `x_test` after each iteration.

Could anyone give me some pointers here please? As I just can't find the answer to that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

My code:

```
from random import random
import random
from math import exp, pow
import math
from random import randint

amp = 0.85
x0 = 2.0

def overwrite(x):
    global x0
    x0 = x

for n in iter(overwrite, 10000):
    uniform = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if uniform < 0.5:
        sigma_int = 1
    else:
        sigma_int = -1
    sigma_uni = round(random.uniform(0, 1),5)
    x_test = foobar(2.0) + sigma_int * amp
    P = (exp(-pow(x_test, 2))) / (exp(-pow(x0, 2)))
    if (P > sigma_uni):
        f = open('pyton.txt', 'a')
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (float(x_test), float(P)))
        f.close()
```

Comment: At end of loop, set `x0 = x_test` ?

Comment: `x0 = x_test` in your loop?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are defining  global x0, you can call it in the loop itself. After observing your code I think you are not assigning the value of 'x_test' to 'x0'. So just do it inside the loop.
To confirm if its working or no, you can put a debug statement like:
print(x0) after substituting the value which will give you idea if its working or no. Trying with print debug is the best way to check the problem.